# T-SQL : add Time to Datetime2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datetime, dateadd

I want to add up a `DateTime2` and `Time(7)` values

```
DECLARE @createdAt datetime2 = '2023-03-11 23:08:56.990'
DECLARE @dayOffset time(7) = '04:00:00'
```

So that by adding the 2 values I'd get `'2023-03-12 03:08:56.990'`
Eventually I also want to do the same thing but by subtracting so I'd get `'2023-03-11 19:08:56.990'`

I found different ways to add both of theses values but it always removes the time part of `DateTime`

```
DECLARE @createdAt datetime2 = '2023-03-11 23:08:56.990'
DECLARE @dayOffset time(7) = '04:00:00'

SELECT
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, @dayOffset, @createdAt), CONVERT(DATETIME2, @dayOffset))

SELECT 
    DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, COALESCE(@dayOffset, '00:00:00'), @createdAt), CONVERT(DATETIME2, COALESCE(@dayOffset, '00:00:00')))
```

But both return `2023-03-11 04:00:00.0000000`.

What would be the proper way to do this?

Comment: By way of explanation, when you use [`DateDiff`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to get the number of `day` boundary crossings the result is an `int` (`select DATEDIFF(DAY, @dayOffset, @createdAt);` returns `44994`.). That is where you are losing the `@createdAt` time-of-day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way:

```sql
DECLARE @createdAt datetime2 = '2023-03-11 23:08:56.990'
DECLARE @dayOffset time(7) = '04:00:00'

select dateadd(ms, datediff(ms, 0, @dayOffset), @createdAt) -- add
select dateadd(ms, -datediff(ms, 0, @dayOffset), @createdAt) -- subtract
```

Basically, it converts the time value into milliseconds, and then adds / subtracts it to your date

Comment: Thank you, that's so simple and so elegant

Comment: Aside: A [datetime2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) can have a precision of 100ns, so this _might_ cause truncation. 'Tis rare to find a user concerned with [clunks](http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/academic/computer-science/history/pdp-11/rsx/decus/rsx89b/374101/readme.clu).

Comment: @HABO, that's true, if time value has those, it will not be correct. Let's hope it's not a deal breaker for the OP